# Print out value of assign from smarty plugin before plugin is called

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I am trying to develop an advertising system around smarty. So i came up with a plugin which when spitted out on the page looks like this:

```
{load_ad id=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b}
```

The trouble is that inside that function i have a variabled that is assigned called AD_HEAD.

Now AD_HEAD is suppose to show up above the  tag.

So a basic html will look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
{$AD_HEAD}
</head>
<body>
{load_ad id=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b}
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see AD_HEAD is placed higher then load_ad.

Trouble is since it is placed higher it will remain empty but when i put it lower then load_ad it will work.

How can i get this to work, or will i need to develop this differently?

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the `load_ad` function to assign two Smarty variables, `{$AD_HEAD}` and `{$AD_BODY}`?

Your tpl will then look like

```
<html>
<head>
{load_ad id=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b}
{$AD_HEAD}
</head>
<body>
{$AD_BODY}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Trouble is im going to have multiple advertisements on the page. So there will be multiple "{load_ad id=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b}" instances. AD_HEAD isn't mandatory for all advertisements as only some advertisements require code in the header. What AD_HEAD is suppose to do is append all the advertisement codes into one variable and echo it out when all the looping is done throughout the process.

Comment: How about setting up the two variables as an arrays? Then do a `foreach` on each of them. Can you post the code, I'll have a better idea of how to help then.

Comment: I think what I said above still won't work actually. If you post the code of your plugin, I'll be able to help more. Take out anything you don't want published, just leave in the function calls and assignments.

Comment: Hi the code goes as follows:

function smarty_function_load_ad(array $params, &$smarty)
{

 foreach($banner_list as $banner_id=>$banner) {
  
  $ad_head = $smarty->getTemplateVars('AD_HEAD');
  
  $smarty->assign('AD_HEAD', $ad_head . ' ' . d($banner['header']));
  
  $ad_footer = $smarty->getTemplateVars('AD_FOOTER');
  
  $smarty->assign('AD_FOOTER', $ad_footer . ' ' . d($banner['footer']));

  return d($banner['body']);
  
 }
 
}

Comment: I can't seem to get it working. Look like you'll need to design it a different way. Can you generate all the advert stuff in php, put it into an array, assign that array to Smarty and then output $array[key] style like normal? Other than that, you could look at pre/post_filter and output_filter function of Smarty - they can modify the tpl before compiling, after compiling, and before output. Let me know what route you take.

Comment: Apparently the issue has to do with the scope of variables. I read somewhere on the smarty forum that when they release 3.2 they will make it possible to perform this functionality.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know! Have you tried to load the ads a different way?